# Custom button example not working

Tags: android

I am newbie in android application development.
I am using the Form Stuff example given on http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html. In this i have used the custom button example.

My code is as below:

```
    package com.example.helloformstuff;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class HelloFormStuff extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on clicks
                Toast.makeText(HelloFormStuff.this, "Beep Bop", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });    

    }
   }
```

Its showing following error:

```
The type new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){} must implement the inherited 
     abstract method DialogInterface.OnClickListener.onClick(DialogInterface, int)
    - The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not 
     applicable for the arguments (new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){})
```

I am unable to figure out the reason for such error.

Please help me on this.

Thanks

Pankaj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener with

import android.view.View.OnClickListener

Rest of the code remain unchanged will execute the code perfectly.

Comment: Do you know why this is written this way? Why there cannot be only one listener?

Answer (score 3):

You're using the wrong OnClickListener. Use this code instead:

```
   button.setOnClickListener(new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // Perform action on clicks
            Toast.makeText(HelloFormStuff.this, "Beep Bop", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Roflcoptr for replying. I have modified the code according to your suggestion but i ma getting following error now:- DialogInterface cannot be resolved to a type
 - The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not 
  applicable for the arguments (new OnClickListener(){})

Comment: Have you imported the package android.content? You could also use android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener

Comment: Yes you can see from the above code i have imported the android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener

Comment: Try to remove the import and the use 'new android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener' directly as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You are implementing the wrong OnClickListener.  Try View.OnClickListener:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on clicks
            Toast.makeText(HelloFormStuff.this, "Beep Bop", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks zack for replying to use your code i have to remove the import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
as i have already imported view ?